# Not able to Get the Token youtube-data-api

Tags: php, zend-framework, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gdata

Accordiong to the documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application 
It is said that, In order to obtain the token, we need to send a client ID and, possibly, a client secret , So I am done upto that code part, BUt when I run the code, the token is empty.

```
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';
session_start();

$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'myclientid';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'mysecreatID';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');

$redirect = filter_var('http://youtubeupload.net/update_video.php',
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);
echo 'token: '.$client->getAccessToken(); //No token is displayed
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, read about the OAuth Protocol.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth

http://oauth.net/

You need a **REQUEST TOKEN** first!

A request token is used to get access to a resource on a server.

This request token has to be used, to redirect the user to the **authorize** endpoint!

If the user granted access for your application, he will get redirected to your **callback** url with the **token** added to the url.

If you allready have an **access token**, you may need to exchange it, because it is timed out.

Or, if you have a **request token**, change it to an **access token**.

Normally, OAuth endpoints look like that:

```
/oauth/request_token
/oauth/authorize
/oauth/access_token
```